# whois wildcard search on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wildcard, whois

I'm trying to search all domains that start with "marha" and end with ".com" using the Ubuntu terminal.

This is what I'm trying:

> whois -H marha%.com

However, this does NOT give me any results.

Is there an Ubuntu-specific syntax or something I'm missing? I've checks the docs but not successful in finding it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't found anything in the docs because it doesn't support it. You need an external tool to simulate it (search the web, plenty of people have written scripts; it's not hard). Remember that it can quickly be querying lots and lots of domains and on some systems you may end up being blocked on some for abuse.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me hours of work. I was trying to see how many domains matched mine (marhaonline.com)...